# pfSense inaccessible from LAN

Tags: networking, router, dns, lan, pfsense

My pfSense ( pfSense version 2.3.4, FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p19) homemade router from older PC was working just fine for few months but it suddenly stopped working and is inaccessible from any LAN devices - can't access web GUI or ping it. Windows says that the DNS server is not responding. pfSense it self can ping LAN devices and WAN addresses. If anyone has other suggestion then reinstalling it I would be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's a firewall rule that's blocking out the whole LAN segment?
If you have SSH access to the pfSense console you can try to disable (very temporarily) all the firewall rules:

Turn firewall off:

```
pfctl -d
```

Turn the firewall back on:

```
pfctl -e
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to connect to pfSense web GUI - still no internet access for LAN - and it seems there was an error in pfSense's code - arpresolve: can't allocate llinfo for x.x.x.x on WAN interface; transmission error: 0x90 on LAN interface.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found thanks to the previous answer is:

1. Go to router, start shell - option 8 - and turn off firewall with `pfctl -d`
2. Go to web interface > Diagnostics > Factory Defaults
3. Set again interfaces and options
4. On web interface go to Diagnostics > Backup & Restore > create backup

I tried to use the backup I created when I was having trouble with connecting to pfSense and it had the same problem.